# Disable Visual Studio 2017 Sign In Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, settings, default, startup

Hi I am a sys admin and I am using sccm to deploy VS to a bunch of PCs.

My problem is this: Every user that has not been logged in on a station gets the content of his/her user folder copied from manually constructed default folder template. VS after first launch dislays a white window with Sign In or skip option. I want that behaviour disabled in the default folder template or by some script in powershell or cmd.

I have done some research and found nothing on google nor by inspecting the user configuration file in

```
C:\Users\login\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings
```

The Sign in Window can be of course skipped and it will not show if the same user logs in on the same station. That condition is sadly not fulfilled in majority of cases.

I tried skipping it and doing diff to the settings file and to the whole user folder, but to no avail.

My question is: Is this behaviour of VS 2017 optional and if so, how to disable it with any of the above mentioned?

Many thanks for every response.

What I have found: http://www.itninja.com/question/disable-welcome-sign-in-visual-studio-first-start. :-(

Answer (score -2):

Copy %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version\privateregistry.bin from existing user to the default profile

Comment: This file is already in the default folder prototype. It was copied from the profile where the login window does not appear but when copied to the prototype profile folder it has no effect whatsoever. THX for the answer anyway. I will keep looking for a solution.